# Is there any way to change <p> tag in wordpress? I think Slider revolution & shopping cart is causing SEO problem

Tags: html, tags, shopping-cart, revolution-slider

I think `<p>` tag is causing SEO problem for my site.
Recently i changed the theme and suddenly i see my search visibility is falling down, I have put all the tag and content identical to my previous site but i cannot find any other reason except `<p>` problem causing by Slider Revolution and my wordpress shopping cart in the menu bar.
YOAST plugin is showing "**Your keyphrase or its synonyms do not appear in the first paragraph**" the i checked my source code and found there are 6 `<p>` tag before my actual content.
Here is some of them:

```html
<div class="shopping-cart-wrap">
  <div class="shopping-cart-inner">
   
      <p class="buttons top-position">
    <a href="https://pixiworker.com/cart/" class="button view-cart">View Cart</a><a href="https://pixiworker.com/checkout/" class="button checkout">Checkout</a>   </p>

      <ul class="cart_list product_list_widget empty">
    <li>No products in the cart.</li>   </ul>
   <div class="shopping-cart-bottom" style="display: none">
    <p class="total">
     <strong>Subtotal:</strong> <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>0.00</span>    </p>
    <p class="buttons">
     <a href="https://pixiworker.com/cart/" class="button view-cart">View Cart</a><a href="https://pixiworker.com/checkout/" class="button checkout">Checkout</a>    </p>
   </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

and for the slider revolution:

```html
<p class="rs-p-wp-fix"></p>
   <rs-module-wrap id="rev_slider_2_1_wrapper" data-alias="retouch-38746" data-source="gallery" style="background:transparent;padding:0;margin:0px auto;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;">
    <rs-module id="rev_slider_2_1" style="display:none;" data-version="6.1.5">
     <rs-slides>
```

You can also see the source for this website: https://pixiworker.com/

**Can anyone help me out?**

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I resolved the rev slider issue.
i've changed the php code of revslider from revslider>includes>output.class.php
and changed `<p>` tag to `<a>` tag and i hope it will resolve my issue.
now it looks like,

```
<a class="rs-p-wp-fix"></a>
        <rs-module-wrap id="rev_slider_2_1_wrapper" da........
```

and i've move cart from the menu bar.